# How do I resolve IMAP connectivity error?

Tags: php, email, error-handling, imap, imap-open

Can anybody help regarding this issue. The email didn't received through the imap_open function. I have seen a problem with this function.

```
imap_open($hostname, $username, $password) or die('Cannot connect to Server: ' . imap_last_error());
```

First url with port

```
$hostname = '{imap-mail.outlook.com:143/imap}INBOX';
```

Second URL with port

```
$hostname = '{imap-mail.outlook.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
```

I want to resolve this problem using imap_open function.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `The email didn't received through the imap_open function` - What exactly does that mean? What are you expecting that function to do? It only opens a stream to the mailbox on the server and returns an `IMAP\Connection` instance on success (or `false` on fail). It doesn't fetch the emails on it's own.

Comment: IMAP is increasingly considered a "legacy" protocol [mostly due to authentication constraints] and less and less supported by major providers. IIRC O365 specifically requires legacy authentication be turned on, which I think is now disabled by default and/or causes O365 to complain all the time. For better or worse, major mail providers seem to be moving to proprietary APIs for mail.

Comment: If imap_open doesn't work, you might want to check for firewall issues.